# Reduction of an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}_3$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, local-field

Every elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has a minimal integral Weierstrass model of the form $$ E: y^2 = x^3+Ax+B $$
with $A,B\in\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Here is a problem that I've run into. Suppose $p=3$ and define $E/\mathbb{Q}_3$ as above. I can reduce the coefficients of $E$ modulo $3$ in the naive way to get an elliptic curve $\overline{E}/\mathbb{F}_3$ as follows: $$ \overline{E}:y^2 =x^3+Ax+B \pmod 3 $$
For most pairs $A,B\in\mathbb{Z}_3$, such an $\overline{E}$ will be non-singular. However, **Theorem 4.1** in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves tells me the following:

> Let $E/\mathbb{F}_3$ be an elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation $$ E:y^2 = f(x) $$ where $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is a cubic with distinct roots in an algebraic closure. Then $E$ is supersingular if and only if the coefficient of $x^2$ in $f(x)$ is zero.

So by following **my procedure** as defined above, it **seems like** the reduction of every elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}_3$ will give me a supersingular elliptic curve. But this goes against my intuition that most elliptic curves over finite fields are ordinary (as the name suggests). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The statement that every elliptic curve can be expressed by an equation in Weierstrass form only holds over fields whose characteristic is not divisible by 2 or 3, and I suspect this is what is causing your problem.

Comment: It seems like that should be the case. But isn’t $\mathbb{Q}_3$ characteristic zero?

Comment: I don't think that *the minimal* model (over $\Bbb{Q}$) can always be written in *the short Weierstrass form*. See for example [this LMFDB entry](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/777/b/1). I would expect this to bleed to the $p$-adics also, when $p=2$ or $3$.

Comment: Or, if you insert the coefficients of $y^2=x^3-432$ into the LMFDB search engine, it takes you to the entry of [the curve $y^2+y=x^3-7$](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/27/a/3). This is because the former is not minimal at $p=2$, and there is no short form minimal model for this curve.

Comment: My terminology was probably a bit off above. I don't remember this stuff too well. It's been 20 years since I really delved into Silverman (and the continuation thereof). Anyway, the combination of integrality and minimality occasionally forces us out of the short form.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I will try a few examples now to really convince myself.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're correct that over $\mathbb{Q}_3$ one is not garunteed a minimal model in Weierstrass form, however the statement OP makes is still true. The discriminant is $-16(4a^3 - 27b^2)$ so unless $a \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ then $E$ has good reduction and the equation *is* minimal at $3$.

Comment: @klien4 You might want to think about the following - clearly you can put an elliptic curve in the form you have, but I suspect that your error is that it is *not* true that for *almost all* (in some rigorous sense in terms of a Haar measure) isomorphism classes of elliptic curves $/\mathbb{Q}_3$ have a *minimal* ***short*** Weierstrass equation.